# video player which can step forward and backward frame by frame smoothly

Tags: video, mediaplayer

I am looking for a video player which can allow me to step forward and backward frame by frame by using keyboard shortcut.

I have video with 24fps.

Presently i am using mpv.

I am trying the following shortcuts:

. Step forward. Pressing once will pause, every consecutive press will play one frame and then go into pause mode again.
, Step backward. Pressing once will pause, every consecutive press will play one frame in reverse and then go into pause mode again.
Step Forward works smoothly but stepping backward works very slaggy.

I also tried

https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/4019#issuecomment-330727387

> Djvview has the option of caching decoded frames in memory, is this
>   possible with mpv? Maybe with a user specifiable RAM cache, like
>   djvview? I use mpv for previewing renders and so on, the ability to
>   smoothly play backwards would be really useful.
>
> http://djv.sourceforge.net/

djv_view caches few seconds doest not cache the entire.

Is there any video player where i can smoothly play around with frames

Answer (score 1):

MPV with all the caching enable does this pretty well. A backward frame seek is quite fast for me.  Faster than DJV on the default settings.

Enable lots of caching with some options like these: `--demuxer-seekable-cache=yes --cache=yes --demuxer-max-back-bytes=100M --hr-seek=yes --demuxer-cache-wait=yes` (not a well researched or exhaustive list)